# Transparency of UIScrollView on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, transparency, background-color

I have xib in which i have couple of views, but basically structure looks like this:

```
- view
   - Image View (fullscreen image)
   - some views...
   - Table View (style: Grouped)
```

In xib editor when editing Table View I can set background in its Table View and View sections. I set them to clear color. On iPhone this Table View background is indeed transparent and I can see my full screen image 'under' it but on iPad background of Table View is gray, no matter what and where I will set.

My question is how to achieve transparent background of Table View on iPad in presented case? iOS I'm working on is 5.1.

Comment: Have you taken a groupedTableView?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by that. Type of this Table View is "Grouped".

Comment: Have you used yourTableView.style= UITableViewGroupedStyle?

Comment: This property is read only. But as i said earlier type of this Table View *IS* Grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix for my issue was as follows:

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

This made background transparent on iPhone and iPad.